# Bind custom attribute value

Tags: angularjs

I have a json with current settings. Its structure is something like this:

```
{
    color: '#111111',
    opacity: '0.1',
    text_area: {
        color: "#222222"
        opacity: "0.2"
    },
    something_else: {
        color: "#333333",
        opacity: "0.3"
    }
}
```

Then I have some inputs on my page where user can select color values. Selection is performed by a [MiniColors](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/). When you define that user should select not only a color but an opacity as well, minicolors stores selected opacity value as attribute in input tag called "data-opacity". The color value (hex one) is stored similar way as any text in input.

To test things out, I have added to my html this:

```
{{settings.text_area.color}}
{{settings.text_area.opacity}}
```

My **input** tag looks like this:

```
<input id="ta" ng-model="settings.text_area.color" data-opacity="0.8"></input>
```

Of course, I can see only that the color value is displayed when I change a color, but how do I bind **data-opacity** attribute value (that will be changes each time user will select a new opacity value) to **settings.text_area.opacity** variable? It seems that I do have to make my own directive for that, no?

Comment: How about choose an answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

As easy as setting the `{{ settings.text_area.opacity }}` inside `data-opacity`! It'll update as soon as your opacity model is changed by whatever other input you have.

```
<input id="ta" ng-model="settings.text_area.color" 
               data-opacity="{{ settings.text_area.opacity }}" />
```

Comment: Will that work as a double-binding even when jquery sets the value to the attribute data-opacity? Wont "{{ settings.text_area.opacity }}" be overriden?

Comment: Yes it's double binded. Anywhere you change this model it'll update all of them

Comment: Nice! I thought $('#ta').attr('data-opacity', '0.7'); broke the model binding on the element and that angular didn't "notice" the change.

Comment: The nice thing about ng-model is that I strictly defines a varible to bind for particular dom element. I bet there is a similar approach but to "watch" for custom attribute, like data-opacity for partiular dom element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think so. Of what I know you'll just have to listen to changes made to #ta with angulars dirty checking (watch) with a custom method that looks at the attribute data-opacity. Just make sure that angular is triggered when choosing opacity/color so that the watch is triggered to check if the value changed. Maybe you'll have to do it with a manual  scope apply().

```
watch('watchForOpacityChange', function() {  
  // do the stuff you want to do with the new data here  
});  

function watchForOpacityChange() {  
  return $element.attr('data-opacity'); //jquery light method attr is available on $element  
}
```

That was just some sample code for what you would want and need in you directive. You could wrap the whole jquery functionality but that would mean more work.

Regards
Tobias

Comment: Wouldn't this watch for all dom element that have data-opacity attribute? And how will I know to what setting to apply it when I have a lot of dom element for choosing color?

Comment: The watch method will only be triggered by the one element associated with this directive. It was just some of the code you would want to have in your directive. If you inject the ngModel to your directive and you set your ng-model to settings.text_area instead you will know which object to update the opacity and color to.

Comment: ah, I see, great, seems that it is what I am looking for. Will test it out.